# Amazon AWS SNS For Sending SMS could not send SMS , return status is "WaitingForActivation"

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, asp.net-core-1.0

I am new to AWS and trying to setup my system to send SMS to end user post booking as a confirmation message.

I did below till now :

```
AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient smsClient = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(key, secreteKey, token, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);

             var smsAttributes = new Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue>();

             MessageAttributeValue senderID = new MessageAttributeValue();
             senderID.DataType = "String";
             senderID.StringValue = "my-sender-id";

             MessageAttributeValue sMSType = new MessageAttributeValue();
             senderID.DataType = "String";
             senderID.StringValue = "Transactional";

             CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
             CancellationToken token = source.Token;


             smsAttributes.Add("SenderID", senderID);
             smsAttributes.Add("SMSType", sMSType);

             PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest();
             publishRequest.Message = "This is 2nd sample message";
             publishRequest.MessageAttributes = smsAttributes;
             publishRequest.PhoneNumber = "my number with + and country code";

             Task<PublishResponse> result = smsClient.PublishAsync(publishRequest, token);
```

however I did not receive any SMS.

As i debug the code , I saw below message : 
[image]

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resoved this issue with below changes , 
changes the SenderID to AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID
and  sMSType  to AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType

So in total , overall flow is like

1. Download nugget for AWSSDK for simple notification v3.3.5.12
2. use below simple method for sending single SMS.

below is the working snippet with C#.NET core 1.1

```
AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient smsClient = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(my_access_key, my_secret_key, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);


                var smsAttributes = new Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue>();

                MessageAttributeValue senderID = new MessageAttributeValue();
                senderID.DataType = "String";
                senderID.StringValue = "mySenderId";

                MessageAttributeValue sMSType = new MessageAttributeValue();
                sMSType.DataType = "String";
                sMSType.StringValue = "Transactional";

                MessageAttributeValue maxPrice = new MessageAttributeValue();
                maxPrice.DataType = "Number";
                maxPrice.StringValue = "0.5";

                CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
                CancellationToken token = source.Token;


                smsAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID", senderID);
                smsAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType", sMSType);
                smsAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.MaxPrice", maxPrice);

                PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest();
                publishRequest.Message = "This is 2nd sample message";
                publishRequest.MessageAttributes = smsAttributes;
                publishRequest.PhoneNumber = "received phone no with + and country code";

                Task<PublishResponse> result = smsClient.PublishAsync(publishRequest, token);
```

Comment: how to check logs for this coz I tried your code, build is successful but it's not sending SMS nor giving any error

Comment: You can check status in Task result with debugging or you can defined a bucket for SNS report in AWS console and check the report. If you are trying this for the 1st time, AWS limits SMS spending limit to $1 for the account, so you might have to raise a request for increasing SMS Quota limit. Just to check if your Quota is exhausted try sending SMS from SNS console.